# comp.text.tex quasi-defunct?

Tags: pdftex

I tried posting a question to comp.text.tex from my google account, which has worked in the past.  it is pretty non-descript as far as errors go.  either I managed to be classified as a meat-popsicle (spam), or...  most posting these days are announcements, so I suspect this is more general.

Comment: This seems legitimately off-topic.

Comment: TeX.SE provides a META subsite that may be a better fit for your posting. It definitely seems to be the case that many people who used to frequent c.t.t. can be found on TeX.SE.

Comment: In addition to the above: _use a proper client_. I have no issues with `c.t.t.` via EternalSeptember using Thunderbird.

Comment: tried to edit the tag, but meta doesn't show up as a tag for me, and I don't have the rep to create a new one.  it needs to be under tex, though.